# Text on Subfloat images

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats, text

I looked at some posts about putting text on images but could not find an answer that helps me. I would be happy if someone could suggest a new way or simply a way to implement tikz or overpic better, even though \begin{tikzpicutre} or \begin{overpic} hasn't worked for me. Also when I try \put it places the text behind the images.

I am writing a scientific report and I need to number my images as A, B, C, D which are enclosed inside the same \begin{figure} \end{figure}. I assumed because I am using \subfloat tikz or overpic doesn't really work.

Is there a way for me to put **text** on the top left corner of **each subfloat image** and possibly choose the *color*, *font* and the *background* of the text?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdftitle={<pdf title here>}, pdfauthor={<author's name here>}, pdfsubject={<subject here>}, pdfkeywords={<keywords here>}]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{subfig} %for sub figures
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} %use with \mathrm for non italic 
\usepackage{upgreek} % for non-italic greek letters
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[percentpdf]{overpic}
\usepackage[style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}




\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
     \hfill
   \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Images/img1.jpg}}
 \hfill
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Images/img2.jpg}}
 
         \subfloat{\hbox{\hspace{0em}\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Images/img3.png}}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat{\hbox{\hspace{0.5em}\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Images/img4.png}}}
    \caption{ a) img1 b) img2 c) img3 d) img4}
    
\label{fig:imgs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please complete your code (preamble etc.) so we can copy&run it. Answers may depend on what our preamble contains or misses.

Comment: @MS-SPO hello! thank you for the reply. i think, added the Preamble. Please let me know if I am still missing something.

Comment: Perhaps package subfloat is a bit closer to what you want? https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfloat

Comment: There are several ways to overlap text and images (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282619/place-text-on-lower-right-corner-of-picture?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C44.4776 for example).

Answer (score 1):

This uses `\llap`, `\makebox` and `\raisebox` to overlap the text.  The first step is to measure the width and height of the image using a savebox.

I used `\subfloat` for familiarity, but since you know the width, you could just as easily used a subfigure.  The second image was overlaid with a complete subfigure caption.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdftitle={<pdf title here>}, pdfauthor={<author's name here>}, pdfsubject={<subject here>}, pdfkeywords={<keywords here>}]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{subfig}% obsolete
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} %use with \mathrm for non italic 
\usepackage{upgreek} % for non-italic greek letters
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[percentpdf]{overpic}
\usepackage[style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]% friends don't let friends use [H]
  \centering
  \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%{Images/img1.jpg}}
  \subfloat[]{\usebox0%
    \llap{\makebox[\dimexpr \wd0-2pt][l]{% left side
    \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht0-\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]% top
      {\textcolor{red}{Text goes here}}}}}
  \hfil
  \sbox1{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%{Images/img2.jpg}}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\wd1}
    \usebox1%
    \llap{\raisebox{\ht1}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \wd1-4pt}
      \captionsetup{font={color=red}, skip=0pt, singlelinecheck=off}%
      \caption{A subfigure caption}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{2pt}}}
  \end{subfigure}
  
  \vskip\floatsep
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%{Images/img3.png}}}
  \hfil
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image}}%{Images/img4.png}}}
  \caption{ a) img1 b) img2 c) img3 d) img4}% begins and ends with \par  
\label{fig:imgs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: this did not work for me so I decided to switch to \minipage. I did something like 

'''\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\llap{\makebox[0pt][l]{\textcolor{red}{A}}}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/usaf_1.26_2.jpg}
\end{minipage}'''

but now the text just appears on the top left corner of the minipage and not on the picture.

Comment: The \llap has to go **after** the image.  It overlaps to the left, so it has to be placed to the right of the image.  Also, whatever goes first gets written over, so \rlap won't do.

Comment: Still did not overlap the image, just appeared above it instead

Comment: I don't know why you are trying so hard not to use a savebox.  You need to know how wide and tall the image is in order to place the text from the lower right corner.

Comment: I am not sure how to use it

Comment: You **could** use \settoheight and \settowidth, which use saveboxes internally.  There are several ways to create saveboxes, but one can usually use \sbox0 through \sbox9.  For box register 0, the width is given by \wd0, the height by \ht0 and the depth by \dp0.  One can use \usebox0 to display the savebox (without destroying it).